# How to avoid invalid inputs error while passing form data in python requests?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

I am using Python 2.7 to send post request to [billdesk](https://pgi.billdesk.com/pgidsk/pgmerc/rvvnlaj/RVVNLAJDetails.jsp) website with my customer number to fetch its details.

I am getting invalid inputs error on passing below request.
I also tried with json encoded form data.

```
url="https://pgi.billdesk.com/pgidsk/pgmerc/rvvnlaj/RVVNLAJConfirm.jsp"

payload={
        "service":"BILL",
        "txtCustomerID":"110331033880",
        "txtEmail":"mymailid@gmail.com"
        }

headers={
       "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
       "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
       "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
       "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36",
       "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
       "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       "Connection":"keep-alive",
       "Host":"pgi.billdesk.com"
   }

z=requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=payload)
print z.content
```

I am expecting the bill details in the content, but I am getting invalid inputs error.

```
<td >&nbsp;</td>
<td bgcolor="#ff9966" class="textrvvnl">Invalid Inputs</td>
<td >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >&nbsp;</td>
<td bgcolor="#ff9966" class="textrvvnl">&nbsp;
</td>
<td >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Kindly advise whether I am passing the form data in incorrect format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong headers, try using these ones instead:

```
headers={
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
        "Referer": "https://pgi.billdesk.com/pgidsk/pgmerc/rvvnlaj/RVVNLAJDetails.jsp"
       }
```

hope this helps